# Is there any way to print the whole sentence found with re.search()?

Tags: python, regex, python-requests

```
import re
import requests

# a function to clean all HTML tags and attributes (def Clean_HTML(raw_html))
# returns clean_text
site_URL = input("\n Enter a site URL:")
request_site= requests.get(site_URL)
raw_html = request_site.text
text = Clean_HTML(raw_html)

LIST = [""]
x = input("\n enter the number of words to search for:")
for i in range(int(x)):
    LIST.append(input("\n input a word please:")

for item in LIST:
    match = re.search(r"("item")",clean_text)
    print (match)
```

I need a way to print the whole sentence where it found the match and if possible the whole paragraph.

Comment: Like that you no because you are matching only item words, when does the sentence begin and when does it ends

Answer (score 0):

Something like [this](https://repl.it/@n1ckdm/ConfusedSeashellAccounting)?

```
with open('text.txt') as f:
  lines = f.readlines()

search = "Nulla"
for line in lines:
  if search in line:
    print(line)
```